# Why Won't Fishpig Set the Magento Blog URL Correctly?

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

So, a client of mine has this Magento site set up:

```
http://kharmakhare.com
```

I have actually asked a question about this site before. This time, they want a blog set up at:

```
http://kharmakhare.com/blog
```

Yes, there is one already there. They want to replace that AW Blog with a Wordpress blog integrated into the Magento theme with Wordpress. There's just one problem; I can't get the url to change at ALL.

No matter what I do, the blog always appears at:

```
http://kharmakhare.com/wordpress
```

I try to disable the AW Blog and test the new one at:

```
http://kharmakhare.com/blog
```

But nothing happens. The above url simply redirects to the main site.

All of my Wordpress Integration settings are green (except for "improve your blog"). If I disable Wordpress Integration in the settings, the /wordpress directory STILL appears.

In Wordpress, the site url is set to /blog. The wordpress url is /wp. Whenever I try changing the permalink settings Wordpress fails to create the .htaccess file, so I did it manually... but it always uses /blog in the settings:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Not that it matters much. Even with it set to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It still doesn't work.

This has been a real, real pain to set up. The documentation says its easy, everything I've read says its easy. It just plain won't work for me. I even tried reinstalling the plugin. Then I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin. I also tried (before this) uninstalling and reinstalling wordpress. Nothing works.

I can NOT delete the AW blog without having the new blog to replace it. I can disable the AW blog temporarily, but I can't delete it. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think this must be a bug in the plugin. The ONLY way I could get this to work is to edit the Fishpig plugin's core so that the default route is "blog."

Not an ideal solution, but at least it works. This should not be such a problem, though, the plugin should work as its intended without modifying the core files.

Comment: How did you do this? What file did you edit? I'm actually looking to do the same thing at this point. Nothing seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, upgrade WordPress Integration to the latest version and uninstall AheadWorks Blog extension.

Secondly, I assume that you have installed WordPress in a sub-directory other than 'blog'. For this example, I will assume you have installed it in 'wp'.

To make your blog viewable on /blog, set your Blog Route as 'blog' and your WordPress path as 'wp'. Next, login to WordPress and select Settings > General and change the second URL option (labelled Site address (URL)) to http://www.yourmagentourl.com/blog

You should now be able to view your blog at the /blog URL.

Finally, if WordPress is installed in /wp and visible at /blog, your .htaccess file should reference /wp/ and not /blog

Answer (score 1):

The solution is easy. First fully disable AW_Blog. Don't just disable this via the configuration or via System > Advanced. Either fully uninstall it or delete the app/etc/modules/AW_Blog.xml file and then refresh the cache.

The AW_Blog module uses - rather selfishly - 'blog' as it's frontName. The frontName takes precendence over the dynamic routing system used in Magento WordPress Integration so while AW_Blog is installed, you can't use 'blog' as your WordPress URL.

With AW_Blog fully uninstalled, enter 'blog' as the blog route in the extensions configuration. Finally, login to the WordPress Admin and select Settings > General. Here you will see 2 URLs. The first URL should be the true WordPress URL (if WordPress is installed at /wp then this should be the /wp URL). The second URL should be the integrated Magento URL (eg. the /blog URL)

The WordPress .htaccess file has no effect as this only runs when actually accessing WordPress and isn't ran when accessing Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is more of a question clarification ([disclaimer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124811/why-cant-we-comment-on-questions-when-new-user)) as I am having what may be a related issue.

What happens when you visit http://WWW.kharmakhare.com/blog rather than the shorter url? For me at the moment- www.magento.com/blog resolves correctly whereas magento.com/blog sends me to the home page.

Also, have you tried setting the full path in the wordpress settings? Your question indicates you have set it to /blog rather than the full http://kharmakhare.com/blog ? I believe it should include the full file path.

Comment: When I said the settings in wordpress is set to /blog, I do mean http://kharmakhare.com/blog. In fact, I just checked to see if I may have mistakenly added "www." into the url. It wasn't.

In your case, though, you can ONLY have www.magento.com OR magento.com. Wordpress does the same thing, and its to your advantage to pick one and leave it at that. It hurts your SEO ranking to have your website at more than one permanent location.

Comment: Create a new question and I'll give you a proper answer to it, ok? I was going to downvote you for posting an answer instead of a comment, but then I read the article you posted and realized you couldn't post comments. :P

Comment: @jrConway Thanks for your input. I understand that I should chose on the other for a permanent location, but it's definately an issue if one of the others doesn't work, when I type stackover.com/question into my browser I don't care if I end up at www.stackoverflow.com/question, but ending up www.stackoverflow.com is a problem if you get me? Anyway have opened a question : ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402449/fishpig-wordpress-magento-http-site-com-blog-resolves-to-www-site-com-rather

Answer (score 0):

when dealing with the Wordpress plugin, be sure to clean magento cache (better disable it during editing) and clear your browser cache as well.

Changing routes around between magento and the Wordpress plugin, quickly becomes a nightmare when dealing with invalid caches.

Also check your URL rewites as sometimes as a last resort, a webshop owner will use this to make things work.